# How to work on a remote file on a linux machine using Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, upload, development-environment

This seems like a strange question at first, but I'd really like to know how other people do it: I'm currently creating a node.js application that runs on a Debian server in the internet.

My dev machine is (unfortunately) a Windows 10 Pro system. Now, whenever I tweak a file that I edited locally, I need to re-upload it via SCP or FTP, which is extremely uncomfortable. Usually, I'd simply mount the remote file system into my dev machine's filesystem and work *directly* on the files.

Of course, I can also just work on the remote system via ssh in a console, but that has other disadvantages for me.

I'm looking for the best workflow. What is yours?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow using version control system:

1.) You can make a private repo on Github(private repo is paid) or Bitbucket(private repo is free) of your project.

2.) Update the code repository from your windows system.

3.) Copy the repo on the debian server from bitbucket/github and pull the changes everytime you update repository from local system.

Here is bitbucket [tutorial link for getting started](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/tutorial-learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud-759857287.html)

This will take time because you will have to learn Git.
Link to tutorials:

[Atlassian Tutorial Link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that is almost the same effort as copying over the files. I'm looking for something like: "Hit CTRL-S, Alt-Tab to Browser windows, hit F5... tadaa!" (at least as long as you don't need to restart node)

Comment: You should never really be working right on your "live" files. You can set up git so that when you merge changes into the master branch, it can then push that branch onto your server. Will this take time to learn and master? Yes, but trust us - it will save your butt one day and you will wonder how you got along without proper version control. Once it's set up, it's less work than FTP and safer on a few different levels.

Answer (score 0):

I made reasonably good experiences with [WinSshFs](https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs) where you can mount directories via SSH into your local filesystem.

Comment: I forget to mention it, but I've tried that: unfortunately it does not play along with Windows 10.